# Android Studio Failed to Create MD5 hash for file

Tags: java, android, hash

I am building an Android project with a small team.

After implementing Facebook's Login system, I am no longer able to run my project, although it will build without problems.

The error:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Failed to create MD5 hash for file 'C:\Users\me\folder\app\src\main\java\com\team\app\httpclient-4.5.3.jar'.

If I go to my build.gradle module:app, I can see the line:

```
compile files('src/main/java/com/folder/app/httpclient-4.5.3.jar')
```

If I comment this out, the next compile line fails to make an MD5 hash.

I was able to run it, so I don't think its my path variable or JDK. I reinstalled JDK1.8. I have tried using the Android default JDK. I have added every path I could think of to my EnvVar.

After reading the other 10 SO articles about the same thing, I have made 0 ground.

Below is the full gradle file, but with naming details removed.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.our.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.0-alpha1'


    compile files('src/main/java/com/our/app/httpclient-4.5.3.jar')
    compile files('src/main/java/com/our/app/commons-codec-1.9.jar')
    compile files('src/main/java/com/our/app/commons-logging-1.2.jar')
    compile files('src/main/java/com/our/app/fluent-hc-4.5.3.jar')
    compile files('src/main/java/com/our/app/httpclient-cache-4.5.3.jar')
    compile files('src/main/java/com/our/app/httpclient-win-4.5.3.jar')
    compile files('src/main/java/com/our/app/httpcore-4.4.6.jar')
    compile files('src/main/java/com/our/app/httpmime-4.5.3.jar')
    compile files('src/main/java/com/our/app/jna-4.1.0.jar')
    compile files('src/main/java/com/our/app/jna-platform-4.1.0.jar')

    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if(requested.group == 'com.android.support'){
            if(!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")){
                details.useVersion '25.3.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Again, I am not trying to ask the same question over and over on here, but I have yet to find a solution to my problem.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.
If I made some posting mistakes, please correct me so that I can draw the best attention to this post and not a bunch of people screaming about format.

Comment: Did you try to clean and rebuild your project?

Comment: @GiovanniTerlingen Yes, I did. I even went as far as to delete the build cache, clean, and rebuild.

Comment: Try to disable instant run if enabled. Also check if those files exist in your build-cache directory after a build attempt. Lastly, where is mavenCentral() in your gradle script?

Answer (score 1):

```
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.0'
```

Try to compile like this. I don't know whether this will work or not. But give it a try. Also, try to group compile dependencies together.

Comment: Which os are you using? Windows? Are you using any blocker softwares?

Comment: I am using W10, no AV running, no blockers of any sort.

Comment: Okay, put those .jar files in libs folder. Right-click on those files and add them to a library. Now do a clean build and try to build it. I think this will work.

Comment: Remove those old dependencies from your gradle first.

Comment: Sorry if I sound like a complete amateur (I totally am). Which .jar files? And where is the libs folder? Thank you so much for you effort!

Comment: Right click on app older [TOP FOLDER in project] then new-->module-> import jar/AAR package-> import select the jar file to import-> click ok -> done. Now your jar files will be automatically imported to the project. FIRST, remove current dependencies.  Try this.

Answer (score 1):

I had several building issues on my desktop, and the errors varried. Sometimes `md5` errors, and sometimes errors in my `build` folder.

My solution was to disable my Anti-Virus, and that worked out pretty well. I was using  Bitdefender on Windows.

Comment: I am using Windows Defender; after turning it off and doing a clean rebuild, no luck. Thanks for your input, though. I had seen that AV could be a problem.